# How do I disable sign up in an Azure API Management developer portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

My goal is a publicly available Azure API Management Developer Portal where the users can sign in if they want, but the sign up functionality has been disabled - you have to be invited by us to get a user.

I've enabled the Management API and use the [Sign Up settings page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/signupsettings/update#code-try-0) to PATCH with this body. This returns a 204 No Content, so the call seems to be correct.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "enabled": false
  }
}
```

I would have expected to that sign up was removed and disabled from the portal, but it's not. What I see instead is that 'Username and Password' has been removed from Identities in the Azure Portal. Users can still sign in and sign up even though this is removed, which I find weird.

Has anybody experience the same? Any suggestions to what I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new developer portal, you can remove **Sign up** navigation item and hide it at least from the menu. Don't forget to republish the portal after changes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Also remember to remove the link to the sign up page from the sign in page.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this Sign Up Settings - Update API can only works for legacy Developer portal.

New Developer portal is still in the development stage, and this feature is not available yet.